# Nesting column layout inside a row layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to accomplish a nested scrollable layout which has a left sidebar and a right container that is divided horizontally. Previously I've used [ui-layout](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout) which is still quite new (and buggy).

Given a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/amergin/pen/QbgerG)

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="row" layout-fill>
    <div flex="33" class="blue">left</div>
    <div flex="66" class="green" layout-fill>
      <div layout="column" layout-align="start start">
        <div flex="25">above</div> 
        <div flex="75">below</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

why am I unable to see the nested column layout properly? I would expect `above` to horizontally take 25% of the right-hand side of the page and `below` the rest 75%. What am I doing wrong, or is this even possible using the layout directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```html
<div flex="66" class="green" layout-fill>
  <div layout="column" layout-align="start start">
    <div flex="25">above</div> 
    <div flex="75">below</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to

```html
<div flex="66" layout="column" layout-align="start start" layout-fill class="green" >
  <div flex="25">above</div>
  <div flex="75">below</div>
</div>
```

The reason your original code did not work is because layout="column" does not automatically fill height to 100% of it's containing element.

Comment: Interestingly, your solution _somewhat_ works. [Plunker](http://codepen.io/amergin/pen/wapgEP). The 66-33 division does not work because [there's a bug in angular-material](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3436), but by removing the percentage it divides using 50-50. Tried out with Chrome.